# Do added files become staged in git?

Tags: git

I am reading Pro Git book, and there is the figure that confuses me. It is the [File status lifecycle](http://git-scm.com/figures/18333fig0201-tn.png). It tells that added file become *unmodified*, not *staged*. It also [says](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) *tracked* files are files that were in the last snapshot. So I imaged that when I modify added but not commited file, there will be no need to stage that changes, because there is no saved version of this file in the staged cache. But I was wrong. Does this mean that the "add the file" arrow from *untracked* state should lead to *staged* state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That diagram is a bit confusing, but yes. Adding an untracked file also stages it for commit. The `add` command is best understood as adding changes in the working tree to the index, and then the changes in the index are used to create the next snapshot/commit. So `git add <untracked file>` adds the file to the index (i.e. it stages it), `git add <modified file>` adds a changed file to the index, `git add <deleted file>` removes a deleted file (i.e. if you deleted it without using `git rm`) from the index.

You can see what's in the index with `git ls-files --stage`. You'll see it's just a manifest of objects, their hashes, and their unix-like file mode (and an index number, for things like merge conflict states, typically 0 for all entries). So add and commit a file to a new repo, run that command, and you'll see it listed. `git rm` that same file, then run the command, and you'll see nothing, because you'll have removed the only entry from the index.

Note that the items in the index have a hash. The index is really just a text file (though it's stored in binary) that names hashed items in the object store. When you add any file - untracked or modified - git hashes it into the .git/objects folder, then updates the index with an entry that points to that hash, and has the path/name of that file. That's really all the index (used to be more commonly called the 'stage' or 'staging area', though those names are fading away) is.

The next commit is really just a text file that points to the tree of what's in the index, because the index is basically where you say "this is what I want the next commit to look like." And yes, if you add a file, then change it, you'll have a version of the file in the index, and the more recently updated version in the working tree, so you'll have to add that, too, and git will replace the version in the index with the newly-edited one.